# ME3: unlocking Rebellion and Resurgence pack characters and weapons?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

How do you unlock the new characters and weapons in Mass Effect 3's DLC packs? I've seen plenty of other people playing with them, and I can see the new characters greyed out in the selection menu, but after buying a ton of those annoying random loot packs I haven't unlocked even one.

Are these only found in the 99k packs? If so how many of those packs do I have to save up for to get even one to turn up?

Do you have to play a particular game type? Does having existing characters up to a certain level help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most class unlocks are considered 'rare' so buying spectre packs are the best way of finding them since it guarantees a rare.  If I remember correctly, the 99k packs guarantee 2 rares so may be a good option as well.  Whether or not you get one of the ones in the DLCs is pure luck since there are many rares in the game.

Comment: So after a bunch of packs I still haven't unlocked any new stuff that's just bad luck? Arrrg! I guess if I want to play with the new DLC I'll just have to pay EA & MS over and over again in the hope of maybe getting lucky, but then I guess that's the idea.

Comment: @Keith Or you can play a lot and pay for the pack in credits.

Comment: @svick - that's what I'm doing TBH. If I'd been buying packs with MS points I'd be in for more that I paid for the boxed game by now :-S It works out at something like a premium pack every 4-5 games (on gold difficulty), 20-30 mins to a game. I guess I'd better get on with it.

Comment: @Keith: I've not played much gold but I reckon on about 15k credits for a bronze match and about 30k for a silver. putting that at 6-7 matches on bronze for the psp or 3-4 for silver. I'd have expected gold to be ~2-3 matches per pack...

Comment: The psp are about 2 for every 3 successful gold completions. U earn 72000 credits aprox for each mission completion. So 3= around 216,000 credits. And with psp costing 99k per 2 cost 198,000. So yeah

Answer (score 3):

I have unlocked 2 characters so far. I have purchased about 10 premium and spectre packs each. If you strictly want to unlock characters, the best chance and bang for you're buck would be the premium pack (2 rares for an extra 30k than spectre). I usually stick to silver maches which usually gives me about 100k every 3 missions.

Answer (score -2):

My Mass Effect 3 gave me the vanguard(forgot the name,but it can go through walls) with only a veteran pack. The best would probably be the reserves pack, as it has the highest chance for characters. I want the collector adept character though, it looks boss.